# How to check a text file for text and then store the variables?

Tags: c, fopen, fread

I am kinda new here so I apologize in advance if I don't explain enough, so here it goes:

To give you a picture, I have an fopen command opening and/or creating a text file with the parameter to read/write/overwrite if I am correct

```
fp = fopen("stats.txt", "w+");
```

I have the file written to with:

```
void display_stats()
{
//some math needed for calculations
smod = (STR - 10)/2;
dmod = (DEX - 10)/2;
cmod = (CON - 10)/2;
imod = (INT - 10)/2;
wmod = (WIS - 10)/2;
hmod = (CHR - 10)/2;
amod = (APP - 10)/2;

//print to console
printf("STR: %i(%i)\n", STR, smod);
printf("DEX: %i(%i)\n", DEX, dmod);
printf("CON: %i(%i)\n", CON, cmod);
printf("INT: %i(%i)\n", INT, imod);
printf("WIS: %i(%i)\n", WIS, wmod);
printf("CHR: %i(%i)\n", CHR, hmod);
printf("APP: %i(%i)\n", APP, amod);
printf("-----Saving Throws------\n");
printf("Fortitude: %i\n", fort);
printf("Reflex: %i\n", rflx);
printf("Will: %i\n", will);

// write to file
fprintf(fp, "Level %i %s %s:\n",level,race_r,spec_c);
fprintf(fp, "STR: %i(%i)\n", STR, smod);
fprintf(fp, "DEX: %i(%i)\n", DEX, dmod);
fprintf(fp, "CON: %i(%i)\n", CON, cmod);
fprintf(fp, "INT: %i(%i)\n", INT, imod);
fprintf(fp, "WIS: %i(%i)\n", WIS, wmod);
fprintf(fp, "CHR: %i(%i)\n", CHR, hmod);
fprintf(fp, "APP: %i(%i)\n", APP, amod);
fprintf(fp, "Fort save: %i\n", fort);
fprintf(fp, "Reflex save: %i\n", rflx);
fprintf(fp, "Will save: %i\n", will);

}
```

which outputs this in the file "stats.txt" (depending on what the user inputs)

```
Level 2 Gnome Sorcerer:
STR: 8(-1) //STR=8 smod=-1
DEX: 14(2) //DEX=14 dmod=2
CON: 14(2) //etc...
INT: 13(1)
WIS: 13(1)
CHR: 12(1)
APP: 11(0)
Fort save: 0
Reflex save: 0
Will save: 3
```

now, for the programs second run, I want it to check the file for text and if true, then output that text along with storing all the variables for later use, I currently have:

```
if (fgets(buf, 1000, fp) == NULL) //char buf[1000]/FILE fp if "stats.txt" has no text
                {
                    printf("Please enter in your base stats (no modifiers):\n");
                    enter_stats();
                    printf("Please indicate your characters level:\n");
                    printf("I am a level ");
                    level = GetInt();
                    Race_check();
                    spec_check();
                    printf("------Base saving throws (no modifiers)------\n");
                    saving_throws();
                }
                else //if "stats.txt" has text
                {
                    printf("%s",buf);
                }
                break; //ending of a case statement
```

Please and Thank you for the help, this is frustrating.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Whats going wrong? you allready open the textfile. You could now read it line by line? and then store it into a simple var in your program..

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't written any question, I am guessing it is something like 'it is only reading one line'.

This is because of the `fgets` function which only reads until it gets `n-1` characters **or reaches a new-line character**.

More information [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

Answer (score 0):

```
  FILE* fp1;

  FILE* fp2

     fp1 = fopen("text_to_read","r");

     fp2 = fopen("text_to_write","w+");

     char* s;

  while(fscanf(fp,"%s",s) != EOF)
```

{

```
    fprintf(fp2,"%s",s);
```

}

```
   printf("Its done!!")
```